# Download new duplicity archives only (bash)

Tags: bash, duplicity

I'm using duplicity to save encrypted backups to remote machine A once per day.  I'd like remote machine B to download those backups from remote machine A, but only the new archives so that if A is compromised and the backups are tampered with, B will still have clean backups up to that point.

duplicity first saves a series of files like this:

```
duplicity-full.20140330T145552Z.manifest.gpg
duplicity-full.20140330T145552Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
duplicity-full.20140330T145552Z.vol2.difftar.gpg
duplicity-full-signatures.20140330T145552Z.sigtar.gpg
```

Subsequent backup operations save a series of files like this:

```
duplicity-inc.20140330T145837Z.to.20140330T145933Z.manifest.gpg
duplicity-inc.20140330T145837Z.to.20140330T145933Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20140330T145837Z.to.20140330T145933Z.sigtar.gpg
```

In a bash script, how can I have machine B download only the files it doesn't have yet and not alter the ones it does have?

Comment: You can use `[ -f "$file" ]` to test for the existence of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to sync the backup folders between `A` and `B` and make use of its `--ignore-existing` option to skip files that already exist on machine `B`:

> --ignore-existing
>
> ```
>   skip updating files that exist on receiver
> ```